# Mysql Syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I have a syntax error when running the stored procedure, i get it near the +v_RowIndex+' And ('+v_RowIndex+' + '+v_NoOfRows+')';

Can anyone help me?

```
DELIMITER //; //


CREATE PROCEDURE GetProducts(v_WhereClause  NATIONAL VARCHAR(4000),
v_SortExpression    NATIONAL VARCHAR(128),
v_RowIndex      INT,
v_NoOfRows      INT)
BEGIN 

   DECLARE v_SQL NATIONAL VARCHAR(4000);

   IF (v_WhereClause != '') then

      SET v_WhereClause = CONCAT('WHERE ',char(13),v_WhereClause);
   end if;

   IF (v_SortExpression != '') then

      SET v_SortExpression = CONCAT('ORDER BY ',v_SortExpression);
   end if;

   SET v_SQL = CONCAT('SQLWAYS_EVAL# AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (',v_SortExpression,
   'SQLWAYS_EVAL#                   
[Id],
[Name],
[Description],
[Unit],
[UnitPrice],
[CreateDate]
FROM 
[Product]   
',v_WhereClause,'SQLWAYS_EVAL#   
Row between ')+v_RowIndex+' And ('+v_RowIndex+' + '+v_NoOfRows+')';

   SET @SWV_Stmt = v_SQL;
   PREPARE SWT_Stmt FROM @SWV_Stmt;
   EXECUTE SWT_Stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE SWT_Stmt;

   SET v_SQL = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(Id)
   FROM
   Product ',v_WhereClause);

   SET @SWV_Stmt = v_SQL;
   PREPARE SWT_Stmt FROM @SWV_Stmt;
   EXECUTE SWT_Stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE SWT_Stmt;

END;
//
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems right away:

> ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)

MySQL does not support windowing functions

> [Id]

Square brackets are illegal for quoting object names in MySQL (actually in all databases except SQL Server)

Comment: hmm, i have no idea how else to write the script. I can manage to the delete the square brackets, but the windowing functions :(

Comment: You can do a search on StackOverflow there are several workarounds for MySQL to replace the row_number() function.